# Rails Exception Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable

Tags: mongodb, macos, exception, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid

I want to use MongoDB with my Rails app.

The error is not uncommon but none of the suggestions has worked for me.

I've installed mongodb using homebrew and followed the folowing the steps for same

> brew update
>
> brew install mongodb
>
> sudo mkdir -p /data/db
>
> sudo chmod 777 /data/db
>
> brew tap homebrew/services

I use `brew services start mongodb` to start my mongodb server and get the following response

```
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=39164 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=C168s-iMac.local
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-02-08T12:27:59.072+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-02-08T12:27:59.089+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-02-08T12:27:59.089+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-02-08T12:28:01.222+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1518073081:222686][39164:0x7fffa9db0340], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 2/18944
2018-02-08T12:28:01.330+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1518073081:330012][39164:0x7fffa9db0340], txn-recover: Recovering log 2 through 3
2018-02-08T12:28:01.442+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1518073081:442109][39164:0x7fffa9db0340], txn-recover: Recovering log 3 through 3
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-02-08T12:28:02.563+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2018-02-08T12:28:02.572+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2018-02-08T12:28:02.572+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-02-08T12:28:09.302+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51073 #1 (1 connection now open)
2018-02-08T12:28:09.302+0530 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:51073 conn: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.6.2" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "Mac OS X", architecture: "x86_64", version: "17.2.0" } }
```

Along with this I also start mongo

> cd /usr/local/bin
>   mongod

which starts as expected.

I created my rails app without the `ActiveRecord` and used `mongiod` gem. Next i created the config file using `rails g mongoid:config` and added `Mongoid.load! './config/mongoid.yml'` in `application.rb` file so the config file is loaded.

The content for `mongoid.yml` is

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: mongo_db_demo_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: mongo_db_demo_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 1
```

I created my scaffold for Person and the model was created as expected using `include Mongoid::Document`. I went ahead and used the index of person as my `root_path`.

When i run the rails server, I get the following error

> ActionView::Template::Error (No server is available matching preference: # using server_selection_timeout=30 and local_threshold=0.015):

I know its an exception by rails but cant seem to resolve it for hours now.

I referred [this](https://richonrails.com/articles/mongodb-and-rails) tutorial to get started. The weird thing is that I was successful to set up the app in accessing it and the next day it crashed with this error without any changes. I'm able to access the books's new page `/books/new` but cant seem to save it, hence making it clear that the app is unable to access the database.

I've since uninstalled mongodb twice wondering if the installation has some problem but cant seem to figure out whats wrong.

I understand there are many similar questions but none to resolve my issue. I don't understand what I'm missing and going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**Update**

I was somehow able to run another project that had active record and mongodb in it. [Here](https://github.com/welkie/example-rails-active-record-and-mongoid) is the same. I was successful in saving the data to the `post` model proving that the `mongod` and `mongo` are running and the setup is done correctly. Which means that I'm missing something in my app configuration but yet, I've no clue.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `options:` section from your mongoid.yml? Just to verify that the pool size of one isn't the culprit.

Comment: try to get connected to you DB  using: https://robomongo.org/ and check for errors. What is the error you get when accessing a mongo model via the rails console?